# Use SQL to get highest item with same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to get an SQL Statement that will get me all data with the highest price and link_id = 1
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a13/2

```
ID .. LINK_ID .. PRICE
10 ..    1    .. 100,000
20 ..    1    .. 150,000
30 ..    2    .. 150,000
```

The following returns the correct price/offer but doesnt bring across the correct id and link_id. Is there possible statement? Or do I need to extract the data seperately?

```
SELECT id, p_id, MAX(offer) FROM offers 
WHERE p_id = 1
```

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM offers
WHERE p_id = 1
AND offer = MAX(offer)
```

Comment: do you want all the prices or just the highest one ?

Comment: there is no link_id in your fiddle... please specify you want `prop_id` or `buyer_id` according to your fiddle

Comment: The items here are a little different, but mainly working with the fiddle. I want just the highest one for a specific id. The fiddle shows it better

Comment: in fiddle query is not returning any result.What would be your expected result.

Comment: If prop_id = 2 I expect 10, 2, 1, 100000 and if prop_id = 1 I expect 30, 1, 1, 150000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the highest price record 
try this

```
SELECT id, p_id, offer FROM offers 
WHERE p_id = 1 order by offer desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It is much faster than sub query.

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM  offers o1
LEFT JOIN offers o2 on o2.prop_id=o1.prop_id and o1.offer<o2.offer
where o2.id is null and o1.prop_id=2;
```

example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a13/29

Comment: It is the possible best optimized solution I ever seen..Thanks a lot charvee..I was looking for the same.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [**Working Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a13/23)

```
SELECT * FROM offers JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(offer) as max_offer FROM offers) Max_offer 
ON offers.offer = Max_offer.max_offer
WHERE prop_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
SELECT id, p_id, MAX(offer) FROM offers 
GROUP BY id,p_id,offer HAVING p_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you want to this according to your SQL Fiddle and your requirements

```
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE (prop_id,
       offer) in
    (SELECT prop_id,max(offers.offer)
     FROM offers
     WHERE offers.prop_id=2);
```

Check [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a13/25).